# Writing a simple expression in set notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, notation

I am trying to state that for every pair of even integers, the sum of the two integers is even.

$\forall m, n \in 2 \mathbb Z, \exists a = m + n \ni a \in 2 \mathbb Z$

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you wrote is comprehensible and has the correct meaning, but it is expressed kind of strangely and there is a much simpler way to write it.  In English, what you wrote is

> For all even integers $m$ and $n$, there exists $a$ which is equal to $m+n$ such that $a$ is even.

The second half of this sentence is a pretty convoluted way to say "$m+n$ is even"!  There is no need to make a variable $a$ and say "there exists $a$": $m+n$ is a specific number, not an unspecified number whose existence you are asserting.  So instead you can just say

> $$\forall m,n\in 2\mathbb{Z}, m+n\in 2\mathbb{Z}.$$

Or in English:

> For all even integers $m$ and $n$, $m+n$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

While your expression is logically true, according to your statement, it's better to say:

$$\forall m, n \in 2 \mathbb Z, m + n \in 2 \mathbb Z$$

Answer (score 0):

The symbol $\exists$ is redundant. You could also state:

$$\forall m,n\in 2\mathbb{Z} \ \ and \ \ k=m+n, \ \ k\in2\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: I think it means "such that" for whatever reason

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger, can you clarify your point?

Comment: The symbol $\ni$

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger, you are right, though it is a little confusing with a set membership. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

> Another variant:
>
> \begin{align*}
> 2\mathbb{Z}+2\mathbb{Z}\subseteq2\mathbb{Z}
> \end{align*}

*Note:* The following is valid
\begin{align*}
2\mathbb{Z}&=\{2a: a\in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
2\mathbb{Z}+2\mathbb{Z}&=\{2a+2b: a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: It's more like $2\Bbb Z+2\Bbb Z\subseteq2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: Even equality is correct.

Comment: It is, it's just stronger than the statement we're trying to represent

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: I agree. Adapted to better fit OPs intention.